# Unity rotation issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I'm trying to have a model rotate 90 degrees when a button is pressed - should be simple, right?
Well, the entire system is a buggy mess for some odd reason. I would appreciate some help fixing it

```
transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.parent.rotation.x, transform.parent.rotation.y , transform.parent.rotation.z);
```

Instead, the model just rotates in random directions that seem like they shouldn't at all be related to my code.

I started up the game to rotate the model while it's in play-mode, but the way it rotates seems like it just suddenly changes out of the blue.

I'm really confused by this & would appreciate some help in fixing it

Comment: transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);

Answer (score 2):

You code doesnt work like your think.

`Quaterinion.Euler` expects input in the form of Euler angles, but you are inputing the `(x,y,z)` of a Quaterinon which consists of `(x,y,z,w)` which is why you get really funky rotation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

To get the current Euler Angles of your transform, simply use `transform.eulerAngles` (or in your case, `transform.parent.eulerAngles`)

```
var euler = transform.parent.eulerAngles;
transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler.x, euler.y, euler.z);
```

However this doesnt change the rotation in anyway.
If you want to rotate 90 degrees around the `Y`-axis, you could add 90 like this

```
var euler = transform.parent.eulerAngles;
transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler.x, euler.y+90, euler.z);
```

An even simpler way to rotate 90 degrees around `Y` is ofcourse

```
transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
```